# Flexboxes using percentages

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

https://jsfiddle.net/lars_jensen/djaec2th/1/

I am trying to create a fully reponsive site using nothing but percentages, but I have a problem (see jsfiddle).

What I want is to center all divs on the site, but when I change
the #wrapper-height from px to %, the #wrapper plus the two divs inside disappears.

What is the solution to center the wrapper and still use %???

The HTML is very simple (it's just an example):

```css
    * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

    body {
    background-color:blueviolet;
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }

    #wrapper {
    width:60%;
    height:600px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:coral;
    display:flex;
    }

    .firstDiv {
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:antiquewhite;
    margin:auto;
    display:flex;
    }

    .secondDiv {
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:chartreuse;
    margin:auto;
    }
```

```html
 <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="firstDiv">
            <div class="secondDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I could not find an answer.

Comment: now I got it to work! I needed to add HTML to body in CSS.